# ComponentWillReceiveProps method does not invoke automatically unless there is some API which triggers this through mapStateToProps function

Tags: reactjs

Suppose I have a React class based component named as "ComponentA". Now I have called the action creator (getCategories) inside componentDidMount hook of this component and get its response inside componentWillReceiveProps through mapStateToProps setting up and carrying state inside redux. Now if I switch to "componentB" and trying to get this already setted up state inside componentWillReceiveProps through mapStateToProps of "ComponentB", the componentWillReceiveProps never invoked unless there is an API call which forcing this to invoke. I want to invoke this method of "ComponentB" everytime I switch to this component without API call. Please let me know the correct solution of this problem. Thanks

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: code files are too large to submit here.

Answer (score 0):

As per you description, It is hard to resolve your issue, but this is my try.

As you are switching the component, **assuming you click some link**, you will never get data in `componentWillReceiveProps` because whenever you are switching the component, that component only go through below process as a newly mounted component.

`componentWillMount()` -> `Render` -> `componentDidMount()`.

[This](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html?utm_source=caibaojian.com) is the process for newly mounted component.

The data you want in `componentWillReceiveProps` will only come when you pass data from parent to child and **not when you switch the component**.

As you are using redux, and changing some state in one component (ComponentA), you can access the changed state the another component's (ComponentB) `ComponentDidMount()`.

Comment: but both components are smart means both are connected with redux ... It means when state changed inside redux in "ComponentA" that state change should also be reflected in "ComponentB" when switches to this component because it is also a smart component but it is not happening.